# linq implementation of group by of groups

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

though easily implemented in for loop I'm looking for a neat linq way to implement the below
Let's say I have this list

S1, S1, S1, S2, S2, S1, S1, S1, S2 => {S1, S1, S1}, {S2, S2}, {S1, S1}, {S2}

This is one thing.
In addition to the above add another conditioning when "breaking to Group" (something like prev, current logic)

I did it with lots of code with for each loop - does anyone has an idea if linq can help with those sub group division?

```
foreach (var item in group){
   if (item.member1 != prev.member1 || item.member2 - prev.member2 > 88)
       cut the group till prev item...
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you've shown your for each approach - it's not evident what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: If it comes to "prev-next" LINQ is not the right tool for the job. It is possible but at the cost of LINQ's sole purpose: readability.

Comment: yeah sounds correct, won't use linq here (too bad it's so long code here...) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Tim Schmelter in his comment that LINQ is probably not the right tool for the job here as I can't think of a way you can do this that is as readable as a loop.

The one thing that springs to mind is [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This will call a function for each element in an `IEnumerable` passing in the current element and the return value from the previous call.

Something akin to the following will work but it's not at all obvious (to me at least) what it's doing. The `(string)null` parameter is the first value passed to the `func` so I've added a check for `previousString != null`.

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>()
    {
        "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2"
    };

List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> currentGroup = new List<string>();

someList.Aggregate((string)null, (previousString, currentString) =>
{
    if (previousString != null && currentString != previousString)
    {
        //it's not the first group 
        //and the value is different which denotes a new group
        groups.Add(currentGroup);
        currentGroup = new List<string>();
    }

    currentGroup.Add(currentString);

    return currentString;
});

groups.Add(currentGroup);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
}
```

This prints

> S1, S1, S1
>
> S2, S2
>
> S1, S1, S1
>
> S2

Comment: NICE!! I'll try that out - thanks for sharing this :)